# Inconsistent accessibility; parameter type is less acessible than method

Tags: c#

```
public bool getsetClientes(ClassClientes cli, string id)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parametros.Add("@p1", id);

    DataRow registo = this.GetRow("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = @p1", parametros);
    if (this.isEmptyRow(registo))
    {
        cli.id = "";
        cli.nome = "";
        cli.dt_nasc = "";
        cli.sexo = "";
        cli.morada = "";
        cli.telefone = "";
        cli.contacto_emergencia = "";
        cli.parentesco = "";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cli.id = registo[0].ToString();
        cli.nome = registo[1].ToString();
        cli.dt_nasc = registo[2].ToString();
        cli.sexo = registo[3].ToString();
        cli.morada = registo[4].ToString();
        cli.telefone = registo[5].ToString();
        cli.contacto_emergencia = registo[6].ToString();
        cli.parentesco = registo[7].ToString();
        return true;
    }

public class  ClassClientes
{
    //Variaveis
    string _id;
    string _nome;
    string _dt_nasc;
    string _sexo;
    string _morada;
    string _telefone;
    string _contacto_emergencia;
    string _parentesco;

    //Constructores
    public ClassClientes() 
    {
        _id = "";
        _nome = "";
        _dt_nasc = "";
        _sexo = "";
        _morada = ""; 
        _telefone = "";
        _contacto_emergencia = "";
        _parentesco = "";

    }

    public ClassClientes(string i, string n, string d, string s, string m, string t, string c,string p) 
    {
        _id = i;
        _nome = n;
        _dt_nasc = d;
        _sexo = s;
        _morada = m;
        _telefone = t;
        _contacto_emergencia = c;
        _parentesco = p;
    }

    //Propriedades
    public string id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string nome { get { return _nome; } set { _nome = value; } }
    public string dt_nasc { get { return _dt_nasc; } set { _dt_nasc = value; } }
    public string sexo { get { return _sexo; } set { _sexo = value; } }
    public string morada { get { return _morada; } set { _morada = value; } }
    public string telefone { get { return _telefone; } set { _telefone = value; } }
    public string contacto_emergencia { get { return _contacto_emergencia; } set { _contacto_emergencia = value; } }
    public string parentesco { get { return _parentesco; } set { _parentesco = value; } }

    //Metodos
    public bool VerificaCampos(string crud, TextBox[] tbs)
    {
        string erros = "";
        int a;

        if (crud == "CREATE")
        {
            if (tbs[1].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Nome!";
            if (tbs[2].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Data de Nascimento!";
            if (tbs[3].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Sexo!";
            if (tbs[4].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Morada!";
            if (tbs[5].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Telefone!";
            if (tbs[6].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Contacto de Emergencia";
            if (tbs[7].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Contacto de Parentesco do contacto de Emergencia";
            else if (tbs[3].Text.Length != 1) erros += "Inserir M ou F no Sexo!";
            else if (tbs[5].Text.Length != 9) erros += "Inserir Telefone com 9 digitos!";
            else if (tbs[6].Text.Length != 9) erros += "Inserir Contacto de Emergencia com 9 digitos!";
        }
        else if (crud == "READ")
        {
            if (tbs[0].Text == "") erros += "O id nao pode ser vazio!";
            else if (!int.TryParse(tbs[0].Text, out a)) erros += "O id tem que ser numerico!";
        }
        else if (crud == "UPDATE")
        {
            if (tbs[1].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Nome!";
            if (tbs[2].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Data de Nascimento!";
            if (tbs[3].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Sexo!";
            if (tbs[4].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Morada!";
            if (tbs[5].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Telefone!";
            if (tbs[6].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Contacto de Emergencia";
            if (tbs[7].Text == "") erros += "Inserir Contacto de Parentesco do contacto de Emergencia";
            else if (tbs[3].Text.Length != 1) erros += "Inserir M ou F no Sexo!";
            else if (tbs[5].Text.Length != 9) erros += "Inserir Telefone com 9 digitos!";
            else if (tbs[6].Text.Length != 9) erros += "Inserir Contacto de Emergencia com 9 digitos!";
        }
        else if (crud == "DELETE")
        {
            if (tbs[0].Text == "") erros += "O id nao pode ser vazio!";
            else if (!int.TryParse(tbs[0].Text, out a)) erros += "O id tem que ser numerico!";
        }

        if (erros == "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erros);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void preencherCampos(ClassClientes cli, TextBox[] tbs)
    {
        tbs[0].Text = cli.id.ToString();
        tbs[1].Text = cli.nome.ToString();
        tbs[2].Text = cli.dt_nasc.ToString();
        tbs[3].Text = cli.sexo.ToString();
        tbs[4].Text = cli.morada.ToString();
        tbs[5].Text = cli.telefone.ToString();
        tbs[6].Text = cli.contacto_emergencia.ToString();
        tbs[7].Text = cli.parentesco.ToString();  
    }

    public void limpar(TextBox[] tbs)
    {
        _id = "";
        _nome = "";
        _dt_nasc = "";
        _sexo = "";
        _morada = "";
        _telefone = "";
        _contacto_emergencia = "";
        _parentesco = "";

        foreach (TextBox tb in tbs)
        {
            tb.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

there, `ClassClientes` is all there; I have all classes `public`.

error message:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.ClassClientes' is less accessible than method 'AAR_CLASSES.aar_mysql.getsetClientes(WindowsFormsApplication1.ClassClientes, string)'   C:\Users\JOAO\Desktop\pap\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\AAR_mysql.cs    469 21  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Are you sure `ClassClients` class is set to `public`?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: yes it is, i was looking around here for solutions, it was the 1st thing i did

Comment: Well don't make us guess for it. Show the actual method and class definitions so we can rule that out ourselves. Please add the exact error message as well.

Comment: Any chance class `ClassClientes` is nested or private ? Could you publish `ClassClientes` as well so we could see it's modifiers and if it's inside another class ?

Comment: Could you try rebuild(maybe a clean will help) ?

Comment: its edited now, pretty clean, take a look

Comment: @user3221369, Not me, you can see it's `Jeroen Vannevel` next to your post name.

Comment: yeah i saw it after xD, im new here

Comment: @user3221369, Use rebuild to see if it's compiling (rebuild is a command at VisualStudio that cleans the old executable's and generate new ones).

Comment: @user3221369, I'm going to put it on my Posts, so people could know it fixed the issue if they will encounter it.

Comment: @user3221369, You know how to vote for an answer and accept it ?

Comment: no, i dont, i thought it was automatic

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
internal class ThisActsAsAParameter
{
}

public class ThisIsAPublicClass
{
    public void PublicMethod(ThisActsAsAParameter theParameter)
    {
    }
}
```

If a client in a separate compilation unit was to call `PublicMethod`, the client would need to create an object of type `ThisActsAsAParameter` to pass in as a parameter. Which is impossible, because `ThisActsAsAParameter` is invisible outside the compilation unit.

Just make sure that both `WindowsFormsApplication1` and `ClassClientes` is also public.

Comment: ClassClientes is public

Comment: @user3221369 - Is `WindowsFormsApplication1` public?

Comment: WindowsFormsApplication1 is the name of the project how can i make it public?

Comment: If it's a namespace you can't. I thought it might have been the name of an enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you got 2 Classes that doesn't have sufficient access to view each other.

1. You can move them both to the same location.
2. You can set the appropriate access modifier to public.
3. You can change your design.

**Solution I:**
Use Rebuild to see if it's compiling.
Rebuild is a command at VisualStudio that cleans the old executable's and generate new ones.

**Solution II:**
Check if `ClassClientes` is under another class name `WindowsFormsApplication1` with `private`/`internal` modifiers.
If it is, than change it to `public`.

Comment: i lost you on 1st and 2nd xD